# Zip list of list in python

Tags: python

I was trying to come up with something in one line which could zip a list of list in one line.

```
arr=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
reduce(zip,arr,[])
```

The output I would want would be similar to :
    `zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])`
which is `[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `zip(*arr)` will give you the output so what are you asking?

Comment: zipping list and transposing a matrix are very different . Please explain the similarity.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham Yes . that is what I wanted . You could put that as an answer

Comment: it is in the dupe, another way to do it in python2 would be `map(None,*arr)`